# remove a especific tr child of a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

EDIT: I forgot to mention that those TR were created dynamically.

I'm trying to remove a especific TR that is inside a `<tbody>` when I click in the red X. I can identify the line I just cant remove it.

What I tried:

```
$('#documento_detalhe tbody').find('tr:eq(line_number)').remove();
```

AND

```
$('#documento_detalhe tbody').children('tr').eq(line_number).remove();
```

Any tips on how to select the corret TR? Ill post what i have.

```js
function remove_line(e)
{
    var line_number = $(e).data('line_number');

    $('#documento_detalhe tbody').children('tr').eq(line_number).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  margin_top_30">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <table class="common_table" id="documento_detalhe" class="display" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 50px" class="text_center">Linha</th>
                                        <th style="" class="text_center">Produto</th>
                                        <th style="width: 80px;" class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
                                        <th style="width: 80px;margin-left: 10px" class="text_center"></th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="text_center" id="tbody">
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">1</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="1" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">1</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="2" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">1</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="3" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: `eq` is 0-based, so you would have to substract 1 to your line number.

Comment: Try different variable name  in function remove_line. `e` is reserved for event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, It's not `oneclick`, but `onclick`.

```
<!-- Wrong: oneclick -->
<td data-line_number="1" oneclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>

<!-- Fixed: onclick -->
<td data-line_number="1" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
```

---

That said, the event (`e`) thats passed to the function can be used to get the desired output.

```js
e.parentNode.remove()
```

Will get the paret node (`tr`) of the cell (`td`), and remove it as you can test here:

```js
function remove_line(e) {
  e.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  margin_top_30">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="common_table" id="documento_detalhe" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 50px" class="text_center">Linha</th>
                    <th style="" class="text_center">Produto</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;" class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;margin-left: 10px" class="text_center"></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text_center" id="tbody">
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">1</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="1" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">2</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="2" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">3</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="3" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

We can use that Javascript call on the `onclick` itself so we don't need the function. Change the event (`e`) to the current element `this`:

```html
<td data-line_number="2" onclick="this.parentNode.remove()"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  margin_top_30">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="common_table" id="documento_detalhe" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 50px" class="text_center">Linha</th>
                    <th style="" class="text_center">Produto</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;" class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
                    <th style="width: 80px;margin-left: 10px" class="text_center"></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text_center" id="tbody">
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">1</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="1" onclick="this.parentNode.remove()" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">2</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="2" onclick="this.parentNode.remove()"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text_center">
                    <td class="text_center">3</td>
                    <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                    <td class="text_center">32</td>
                    <td data-line_number="3" onclick="this.parentNode.remove()"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not a typo, i now it was in the example but its not in my code, it wont work on my code, i guess its because the TR were created dynamicly

Comment: the ````e.parentNode.remove()```` works! the wayi was selecting the TR did not work

Comment: Ahh, thought I'd mention it! Glad the `parentNOde.remove()` worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Your line numbering starts with 1, while `eq` starts with 0. But you don't even need the line number. As you have passed `this` to the function, it can just get the surrounding `tr` element with `.closest()` and `.remove()` that:

```js
function remove_line(e)
{
    e.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  margin_top_30">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <table class="common_table" id="documento_detalhe" class="display" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 50px" class="text_center">Linha</th>
                                        <th style="" class="text_center">Produto</th>
                                        <th style="width: 80px;" class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
                                        <th style="width: 80px;margin-left: 10px" class="text_center"></th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="text_center" id="tbody">
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">1</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">it's</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="1" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">2</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">a nice</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="2" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text_center">
                                        <td class="text_center">3</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">day</td>
                                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                                        <td data-line_number="3" onclick="remove_line(this)"  class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                </div>
```

NB: `closest` is a bit more generic than `parentNode`... in case you decide to put your delete button in a more nested structure this can make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can get parent and the remove it.

Try this one:

```js
        function remove_line(e) {
           
             $(e).parent().remove();
        }
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row  margin_top_30">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="common_table" id="documento_detalhe" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50px" class="text_center">Linha</th>
                        <th style="" class="text_center">Produto</th>
                        <th style="width: 80px;" class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
                        <th style="width: 80px;margin-left: 10px" class="text_center"></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text_center" id="tbody">
                    <tr class="text_center">
                        <td class="text_center">1</td>
                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                        <td data-line_number="1" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="text_center">
                        <td class="text_center">2</td>
                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                        <td data-line_number="2" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="text_center">
                        <td class="text_center">3</td>
                        <td class="text_center">sdfsfrewf</td>
                        <td class="text_center">32</td>
                        <td data-line_number="3" onclick="remove_line(this)" class="text_center" style="color:red">x</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the element you want to remove as the parameter `e` you can simply do:

```js
function remove_line(e) {
    $(e.parentNode).remove();
}
```

Also note that there is a typo in your code, make you sure to change `oneclick` to `onclick`.